# How many times does the derivative of the function, in a certain interval, have the same value as the average rate of change of the interval

Tags: calculus

So the question is something along these lines:
[image]
The graph of a function $f$ with $f(b)>f(a)$ is shown above for $a≤x≤b$. The derivative of $f$ exists for all $x$ in the interval $a<x<b$ except $x=0$. For how many values of $c$, for $a<c<b$, does $\lim \limits_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}=\frac{f(b)−f(a)}{b−a}$ ?

How would one try to do this? What I'm currently trying is taking the line of average rate of change i.e. $(a, f(a))$ to $(b, f(b))$ and vertically translating it until i notice a somewhat acceptable tangent. Another thing i was trying to do was count one for every complete concave up on its right (positive slope) and one for the left of a concave down, though i think this might be wrong because i make the assumption that in the interval between the concave up and concave down (or vice versa) that the derivative must have reached the value required and thus 2 matches, but if it didn't then there are no matches.

Comment: It looks to me like there are four such values, one for each of the peaks and valleys in the function. You could try to use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), but without any values I don't think it may be of much use.

Comment: One approach to make it easier to visualize is to subdivide your domain based on the local mins and local maxes of the graph; these points have derivative 0, which is clearly smaller than the slope of the secant line, so drawing these subdivisions can make it easier to use your first approach of vertically translating the secant line (which seems like a good approach to me).

Comment: @Kman3: Note that the Mean Value Theorem does not apply to the interval $[a,b]$ in this case, as the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, my mistake. My apologies.